# C++/OpenCV Segmentation Fault: 11

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to do a small project with C++ and OpenCV (I am fairly new to each). I studied the face detection code provided by OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) to get a basic understanding. I was able to compile and run this face detection code with no issues. I then attempted to modify that code to perform full body detection as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** Function Headers */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );

/** Global variables */
String body_cascade_name = "haarcascade_fullbody.xml";
CascadeClassifier body_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture - Body detection";

/** @function main */
int main( void )
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame;

    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if( !body_cascade.load( body_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading body cascade\n"); return -1; };

    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    capture.open( -1 );
    if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }

    while (  capture.read(frame) )
    {
        if( frame.empty() )
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
        }

        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
        detectAndDisplay( frame );

        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
    }
    return 0;
}

/** @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
    std::vector<Rect> bodies;
    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

    //-- Detect bodies
    body_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, bodies, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(45, 80) );
    //body_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, bodies, 1.1, 3, 3, cv::Size(5,13), cv::Size(45,80));

    for( size_t i = 0; i < bodies.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point center( bodies[i].x + bodies[i].width/2, bodies[i].y + bodies[i].height/2 );
        rectangle( frame, bodies[i], Scalar( 255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);
        //ellipse ( frame, center, Size( bodies[i].width/2, bodies[i].height/2), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    }
    //-- Show what you got
    imshow( window_name, frame );
}
```

Mostly, I just renamed variables from "face" to "body", removed the eye cascade portions and changed the "haarcascade_xxxx".

I am able to compile this using:

```
g++ bodyDetect.cpp -o bodyDetect `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

but when I attempt to run it I just get a "Segmentation Fault: 11"

I have been able to determine that it is due to the "haarcascade_fullbody.xml" assigned to `body_cascade_name`. If I change this value back to the "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" it will run just fine as face detection software again. I do have the xml files copied to the same directory as the .cpp files.

Also, the upper body cascade will not work either, but the profile face cascade will work with the same code (haven't tested all cascades).

I have OpenCV 3.0.0 installed (checked using `pkg-config --modversion opencv`), running MacOSX 10.9.2, if this is relevant. I did have trouble compiling/running slightly different face detection code that appeared to be for OpenCV 2.4.?.

My question is, why would the "haarcascade_fullbody.xml" file cause a segmentation fault, while other cascades do not? Is there a way to correct this issue?

**UPDATE:** When I run the program in `gdb` I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100d0b707 in ?? ()
```

I believe that this indicates that the seg fault is not within one of the functions. I still suspect that the haarcascade_fullbody.xml to be the issue. When this is to a different filter I do not receive the seg fault.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (i.e. using `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did that and had no warnings.

Comment: Did you use the debugger?